# How to Marshall json from one struct to another with different json tags in Go?

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling

I am creating a Go application that consumes data from multiple sources that all have similar data but different structures to their data/responses. These responses need to be marshalled into a common struct that is then sent to another service.

Common struct:

```
type common struct {
   ID         string `json:id`
   GivenName  string `json:given_name`
   FamilyName string `json:family_name`
   Email:     string `json:email`
}
```

One response:

```
{
   "id": "123",
   "first_name": "john",
   "last_name": "smith",
   "email": "js@mail.com"
}
```

Another response:

```
{
   "id": "456",
   "first": "larry",
   "last": "smith",
   "email": {
      "primary": "larry@mail.com"
   }
}
```

How do I marshal a json response with one structure into a struct with a different structure?

Comment: If it wasn't for that email field, you could've created two identical structs with different json tags and simply say v1=v2 where v1 is one struct and v2 is the other. But with that email translation that's not possible. You can still do two structs, and copy from one to the other field by field.

Comment: You cannot use encoding/json with one struct and different names. Dead simple. You either have to have different structs with different tags or use e.g. a map[string]interface{} as the source of serialisation. In any case you will have to copy. Or your write your own JSON serialisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can define different structures according to different sources. Then, transform it into that common structure.

This method is flexible, readable and easy to implement when new sources are added.

The sample code is as follows:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type User struct {
    ID         string `json:id`
    GiveName   string `json:given_name`
    FamilyName string `json:family_name`
    Email      string `json:email`
}

type UserFromMySQL struct {
    ID        string `json:"id"`
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
    Email     string `json:"email"`
}

func (u *UserFromMySQL) GetUser() *User {
    return &User{
        ID:         u.ID,
        GiveName:   u.FirstName,
        FamilyName: u.LastName,
        Email:      u.Email,
    }
}

func main() {
    um := new(UserFromMySQL)

    b := []byte(`{
   "id": "123",
   "first_name": "john",
   "last_name": "smith",
   "email": "js@mail.com"
}`)
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, um)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", um)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", um.GetUser())
}
```

Of course, you can do this by adding redundant fields, define `user` as follows:

```golang
type Email {
    Primary string `json:"primary"`
}

type User struct {
    ID           string `json:"id"`
    GiveName     string `json:"given_name"`
    FamilyName   string `json:"family_name"`
    FirstName    string `json:"last_name"`
    LastName     string `json:"last_name"`
    Email        string `json:"email"`
}
```

Choose the right way for you. I prefer the first one.

Comment: @ polo xue Your first example is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you to separate the struct for each of the data you have.

Golang is a strong type language, so each of the structs should only represent only one data type. This does not only eliminate the Guam code but also reduce the time other develops need to track a type of the data, which sometimes happens in non-strong type language like Python.

Anyway, if you really need to represent those data in the same struct you can write as below.

```golang
type User struct {
   ID         string `json:"id,omitempty"`
   GivenName  string `json:"given_name,omitempty"`
   FamilyName string `json:"family_name,omitempty"`
   FirstName  string `json:"first,omitempty"`
   LastName   string `json:"last,omitempty"`
   PlainEmail string `json:"plain_email,omitempty"`
   Email struct{
    Primary string `json:"primary"`
   } `json:"email,omitempty"`
}
```

Add *omitempty* in the JSON tag, so if the struct is created with user type A then the type B fields will not be represented in JSON. However, I do not recommend this method but if you need to, this is the way.

Anyway, *Email* and *PlainEmail* JSON tag needed to be separated or the compiler will be confused.